# CSS Rounded corners using Divs as corners

Tags: html, css, web

I'm thinking of creating a custom made rounded corners block using only divs, and I was curious to know what you guys think, if that's a good enough approach, or is there an easier way to get a cross browser support (While also supporting older browsers such as IE6)

I'll write a little simple explanation code for you guys to understand easily:

```
<div class="Block" style="position:relative">
    <div>
    Content will go here or something
    </div>
    <div name="TopLeft" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"></div>
    <div name="TopRight" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;"></div>
    <div name="BottomLeft" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;"></div>
    <div name="BottomRight" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;"></div>
</div>
```

In the real code, I'll give each one of them a background, and of course put it in a css file instead of writing it inline like that.

Comment: The simplest way to get full cross-browser support that goes as far back as IE6 is to use images.

Comment: @BillyMoat - au contraire. I recommend CSS3Pie. No need for images.

Comment: If you need to go way back that far, I recommend using Spiffy Corners: http://spiffycorners.com/

Comment: I would also strongly recommend dropping support for IE6 (and even IE7). Particularly when it comes to design frills like this that don't affect the usability. IE6 users are well used to sites not looking great.

Comment: A sidenote (abit OT I agree): Consider that IE6 was released 2001 and IE7 2006. Then consider the evolution of the web since 2001.

Comment: Yea, I thought of dropping support for IE6 but sadly there's still a nice amount of people in my country that are using this browser

Comment: @Don - the point is that losing the rounded corners won't make any different to IE6/IE7 users. They probably won't even notice that it's missing. Sure, maybe you need to make an effort to get the site working for IE6 users, but that doesn't mean you have to make it perfect for them. Also, what country are you in? Unless the answer is China, or you have a specific target audience to cater for, then the number of IE6 users is vanishingly small.

Comment: @Spudley True, the corners aren't the most important thing about the site, still, I wanted my site to function and look the same on most of the platforms and browsers view it. for your question, I'm from Israel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This is a Javascript hack for IE that implements the `border-radius` CSS in old versions of IE.

Comment: Is it safe to use it on a website that's already running? or will I have to fix some issues that it'll cause?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly safe. It only gets loaded in IE; other browsers ignore it entirely. See the examples and demos on the CSS3Pie website for more.

Comment: Coule I please ask why when I view my attempt with CSS3PIE IE8 won't show the box-shadow? IE7 and 6 do show it though, thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind, I think I solved this by adding position:relative, seems like the div simply disappeared without it

Comment: @Don - glad you worked that out. If you do have problems with CSS3Pie, their forums are excellent, and they also have good info on common problems and known issues on the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you need rounded corners in IE6-9 browsers you only need to use CSS3 `border-radius` and one `PIE.htc` file

[**Progressive Internet Explorer**](http://css3pie.com/)

```
div{ border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; behavior: url(PIE.htc); }
```

This works best in all IE browsers

Comment: Yes, pie is nice and clean. If I really can't get away with just giving them square corners in IE9 and earlier, I'd go with pie.

Comment: IE9 supports [border-radius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127319(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Is it safe to use this on an existing website? I don't want this to screw it all up or something

Comment: @DOn You can use PIE for your website at any time. There is NO Harm :) Just remember to add behavior property

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work fine.

You can also add the elements using script, that will make the markup cleaner. I use that approach here: [bytbil.com](http://www.bytbil.com)

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it will work in IE6, but you can use the following:

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

Put that in your CSS for a DIV and it will support most browsers, but again, not sure about IE6...  It does definitely work on IE9, Safari (5+), FireFox(1.0+), Chrome(5+) and Opera(10.5+)...

Comment: this will definitely not be supported in IE6

Comment: Yeah, IE6 is quite outdated, I personally haven't used it in a long long time (in computer time :P )

Comment: It's not going to work on IE6, That's why I asked about the code I wrote above. thanks though buddy

Comment: @Don If it has to be IE6, then I suggest using images in a 3x3 grid with your content in the middle.  Then you can use curved lines in the corners, horizontal lines on top and bottom, and vertical lines on the sides.  Just make them all line up and you're good to go.  (Horizontal and Vertical lines can be a repeating background so they an grow as long as you need).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work, and it's as good as anything to support IE6.

Any solution that covers IE6 is bound to be an awful hack.  I think it's really worth it to wonder if you really need it.  I would prefer just using css rounded corners and let the chips fall where they may.